# PHP: Reading EXIF / IPTC image metadata

Tags: php, encoding, character-encoding

I'm trying to read EXIF and IPTC data from an image. However, some of the content I'm getting is garbled. I think this may be an encoding issue, but I'm not sure.

Here's a code snippet to show the problem:

```
<?php

$path = 'no_exif.jpg';

$exif = @exif_read_data($path, '', true);
var_dump($exif);

getimagesize($path, $image_info);
foreach($image_info as $k => $v) {
    
    var_dump($k);

    if ($k === 'APP13') {
        var_dump(iptcparse($v));
    } else {
        var_dump ($v);
    }
}
```

The image I used for this demo is: https://github.com/ianare/exif-samples/blob/master/jpg/xmp/no_exif.jpg.

Some of the content appears as a series of `?`, like:

[image]

Using an online tool to explore an image's metadata, I think it was able to parse that data correctly. See: https://jimpl.com/results/12d9pv43mJ84fYG9hjxoYMeb?target=exif. The tool labels the information differently (e.g. uses `XPTitle`, etc.), but the data seems right:

[image]

I've tried converting the encoding of the array values to UTF-8, but hasn't helped:

```
array_walk_recursive($entries, function (&$entry) {
    $source_encoding = mb_detect_encoding($entry);
    $source_encoding = ($source_encoding) ? ($source_encoding) : 'ISO-8859-1';
    $entry = mb_convert_encoding($entry, 'UTF-8', $source_encoding);
});
```

**What is actually happening to the metadata? And how do I ensure I get the correct content?**

Comment: The strings in the 'WINXP' segment like 'Title' are all ASCII characters ('?', Hex 3F). Characters which the browser cannot display are output as �.

Answer (score 0):

Some information like title and comments can be obtained from the IFD0 section of the EXIF array. The encoding of this information in this example is UTF-16LE.

```
$path = 'no_exif.jpg';
$exif = @exif_read_data($path, '', true);
$ifd0 = $exif['IFD0'];

$title = trim(mb_convert_encoding($ifd0['Title'],'UTF-8','UTF-16LE'));
$comm = trim(mb_convert_encoding($ifd0['Comments'],'UTF-8','UTF-16LE'));
echo $title."<br>".$comm;
```

Comment: How did you determine that the encoding is `UTF-16LE`? How can I reliably detect the encoding of the EXIF/IPTC data, so that I can convert to `UTF-8`? I thought `mb_detect_encoding` would handle that.

Comment: mb_detect_encoding is not suitable for detecting such encodings. I use a special debugger class that presents strings in the form "D\x00e\x00r\x00 \x00G\x00o\x00a\x00l\x00i\x00e\x00 \x00b\x00i\x00n\x00 \x00i\x00g\x00\x00\x00" and helps detect such encodings.
The UFF-16 character string has 2 zero bytes at the end.

Comment: how can I integrate your tool into what I'm trying to do? I'm sure to run into many other encoding issues. I need a solution for all encodings, not just for this one example.

Comment: It is not possible to recognize any encodings automatically.

Comment: I tried converting from `UTF-16LE`, and the `?` have become `㼿`.

Comment: The strings in the 'WINXP' segment like 'Title' are all ASCII characters ('?', Hex 3F) !! There is nothing to convert there. My answer refers to the entry under 'IFD0'.

Comment: I'm not sure why you think they are all `?`. Look at the screenshot from the online tool. It was able to parse the data correctly.

Comment: Ah! I understand what you mean now. The properly parsed data was not coming from WINXP. I really need to be able to detect encoding more reliably as I have no idea what my inputs will be. What's a solution?